# Non-Repudiation with WebCrypto

Tags: javascript, webcrypto-api

How to achieve non-repudiation with WebCrypto API?

I saw a lot of examples about WebCrypto in how to encrypt/sign text, but the problem always the key is generated during the run-time of the page and this break the non-repudiation.. I believe there should be a way to ask the user about his private key to use.

I think there was a method in Mozilla firefox to ask the user for his key but it is now removed:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Crypto_Sign_Text_Removal

Thanks,

Comment: i would give -1 to the guys that gave you -1 ;)

Answer (score 3):

[Non-Repudiation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Cryptography#Non-Repudiation) usually takes advantage of digital signatures.  The is a library called [PKIjs](http://pkijs.org/) that may be able to help you import a key and generate a signature:

> PKIjs is a pure JavaScript library implementing the formats that
>   are used in PKI applications (signing, encryption, certificate
>   requests, OCSP and TSP requests/responses). It is built on WebCrypto
>   (Web Cryptography API) and requires no plug-ins.

However, the [GlobalSign/PKI.js](https://github.com/GlobalSign/PKI.js) Github repo states:

> At this time this library should be considered suitable for research
>   and experimentation, further code and security review is needed before
>   utilization in a production application.

Answer (score 2):

Author of PKIjs here. There are many production applications built on PKIjs, we included this security review statement to encourage people to make their own decisions on suitability.

To the original question, the use of a run time generated key does not proclude non-repudiation. Non-repudiation is a legal and not a technical concept, principally the issues in non-repudiation are: 1) authenticating the identity of the entity, 2) capturing intent.

To do both of these requires a solution that is designed to provide those properties, no single API can provide this.

To the technical question, no pure Javascript solution will allow you to use keys in the operating system / browser doing so would escape the browser sandbox.

There are several browser plug-ins of varying degrees of usability and quality that once installed let you interact with smart cards. Largely speaking, due to plug-in interoperability and general usability they are not usable enough to be used broadly though.